# Prove that if $x,y\in X$ and $r\in\mathbb R$ are such that $f(x)<r<f(y), $ then $\exists z\in X:f(z)=r$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, connectedness

Let $X$ be a connected topological space and $f:X\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function. Prove that if $x,y\in X$ and $r\in\mathbb R$ are such that $f(x)<r<f(y), $ then $\exists z\in X:f(z)=r.$

Proof. Consider $A=f(X)\bigcap (-\infty,r)$ and $B=f(X)\bigcap (r,\infty).$

Notice that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, open and their intersection is empty.

Now assume there is no $z\in X$ such that $f(z)=r. $**Then** $f(X)=A\bigcup B$, i.e. $f(X)$ is not connected **!** Therefore $\exists z\in X:f(z)=r.$

---

**Why** the assumption of "no $z\in X$ such that $f(z)=r$" implies $f(X)=A\bigcup B$ ?

I think one can see $f(X)=A\bigcup B$ without such assumption: $A\bigcup B=(f(X)\bigcap (-\infty,r))\bigcup (f(X)\bigcap (r,\infty))=f(X)\bigcap ((-\infty,r)\cup(r,\infty))=f(X)\bigcap\mathbb R=f(X)$

Comment: Well $(-\infty,r)\cup(r,\infty)\not = \mathbb{R}$ it is equal to $\mathbb{R}-\{r\}$. (Note that $(-\infty,r)\cup(r,\infty) = \mathbb{R}$ would imply that $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected.)

Comment: I see, now everything it's clear.

Comment: I see the misunderstanding. "if we join $(-\infty,r)$  and $(r,\infty)$  for sure they would fill all $\mathbb R$. I can see it intuitively." But no. Because $r\not\in(-\infty,r)$ nor $r\not\in(r,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to move this Q to the "answered" list:

$$(\neg \exists x\; (f(x)=r))\implies \emptyset= f(X)\cap \{r\}\implies$$ $$\implies f(X)=f(X)\cap \Bbb R=f(X)\;\cap\; [(-\infty,r)\,\cup \;\{r\}\;\cup\, (r,\infty)]=$$ $$=[f(X)\cap (-\infty,r)]\;\cup\; [f(X)\cap \{r\}]\;\cup \;[f(X)\cap (r,\infty)]=$$ $$=[A]\cup [\emptyset] \cup [B]=A\cup B.$$

Comment: .Thank you sir.